# Determine if two arrays of Doubles have their elements in the same order?

Tags: java

I need to know if two equal length arrays of doubles have their elements in the same order.  I am doing as follows and it seems to work but I am thinking there must be a more efficient way.

```
class Box {
    double a, b;
}

boolean orderIsEqual(double[] a, double[] b) {
    Box[] xa = new Box[a.length]; //always same length
    Box[] xb = new Box[a.length]; //always same length

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        Box box = new Box();
        box.a = a[i];
        box.b = b[i];
        xa[i] = box;
        xb[i] = box;
    }

    Arrays.sort(xa, new Comparator<Box>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Box o1, Box o2) {
            if (o1.a > o2.a) return 1;
            if (o1.a < o2.a) return -1;
            return 0;
        }
    });

    Arrays.sort(xb, new Comparator<Box>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Box o1, Box o2) {
            if (o1.b > o2.b) return 1;
            if (o1.b < o2.b) return -1;
            return 0;
        }
    });

    return Arrays.equals(xa, xb);//was deepEquals() - unnecessary
}
```

Comment: Does each array necessarily have the same number of each element?

Comment: as per loop you are inserting at same index in both arrays. so both arrays are having identical elements.

Comment: Well you can make `Box` implement `Comparable<Box>,` that will get rid of the two `Comparators,` but I don't really see why you have `Box` at all unless it is part of the wider picture. And `Arrays.deepEquals()` checks for equality, which is stronger than 'same order', unless you mean that the original data is the same and only the order might be different. Clarification please.

Comment: "in the same order" seems to imply that the arrays must have identical elements--otherwise, how would "order" be defined? If that's not so, please elaborate. If that is so, you can simply use `Arrays.equals`.

Comment: Elements In the same order means like this:  double[] x = new double[]{2.1, 1.1, 3.6, 4.5};        double[] y = new double[]{3.0, 2.3, 5.0, 9.0};   The order of those array elements is 2,1,3,4 in both arrays.  I create two arrays of Boxes because they're going to be sorted in different orders.  If Arrays.sort() returned a new sorted array then I could create just one array but since it sorts the array I needed the 2 arrays.  Yes I think deepEquals was unnecessary. equals() should be good.

Answer (score 1):

While I assume that the question has some hidden problems...

- The box thing there seems completely unnecessary for your task
- Both box arrays (xa, xb) in your example are equal per default, as you put the same stuff into them

...if you only want to check the double arrays, what's wrong about `Arrays.equals(a, b)`? If that method returns false, you know that either the arrays a,b don't contain the same elements or are not in the same order.

Comment: With double[] x = new double[]{2.1, 1.1, 3.6, 4.5}; double[] y = new double[]{3.0, 2.3, 5.0, 9.0}; Arrays.equals(a,b) returns false but the order is equal so I would need true.